# In Debian Error: "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" (pip install)

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, pip, debian, pocketsphinx

*Hello. 

My have a goal, install pocketsphinx in python3 (3.7.5) or python3.8 (3.8.1).

When I try install (in python3) module pocketsphinx, I can see more problem. The last, what I can't solve, this is problem*

- **What's i trying:**
  `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` 
  `sudo apt-get install libevent-dev`
  and of course `sudo apt update` 
  (I don't know, What is the difference between apt and apt get?)
- *Short text error:*

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: <br/>
    command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-62vol71b/pocketsphinx/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-62vol71b/pocketsphinx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-pop7rbfc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile<br/><br/>
    (and very more) 
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result...

    compilation terminated. <br/>
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

(full text error I'd not publish, the text is too big)

(changed)
I don't know how, but then I try : 
`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0` 
Problem leave. HOW? WHY? I tried it!

Comment: Difference between `apt` and `apt-get`: https://askubuntu.com/q/445384 Found in https://askubuntu.com/search?q=difference+apt+apt-get

Comment: Short error text doesn't contain enough information to understand what is going on. Please publish the full traceback and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to be readable.